# Include audio channel as audio track

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Now I'm trying to copy video file, but including only one of channels - Front Center, ignoring the rest of channels.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" ^
       -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side)[FL][FR][FC][LFE][SL][SR]" ^
       -map 0 -map -0:a -map "[FC]" -ac 2 -c:a aac -c:v copy ^
       video_new.mp4
```

And it results with error `Filter channelsplit:SR has an unconnected output`. What's a correct method to include one channel as an audio track?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `channels` option in [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a:0]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1(side):channels=FC[a]" -map 0 -map -0:a -map "[a]" -c copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Also I found that there is "pan" filter: ```-filter_complex "0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[FC]"``` or ```-filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=stereo|c0=c2|c1=c2[FC]"```